# Apache Phoenix unable to connect to HBase

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am a completely new user to Phoenix and have probably missed something slap forehead simple.

- HBase *is* up

  21:44:23/sprue $ps -ef | grep HMaster

  501 55936 55922   0  9:50PM ttys014    0:18.12 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dproc_master -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true - ..
  -Dhbase.security.logger=INFO,RFAS org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster start
- and we can connect to it via `hbase shell` and query stuff:

  hbase(main):010:0> scan 't1'

  ROW                             COLUMN+CELL
   r1                             column=f1:c1, timestamp=1469077174795, value=val1
  1 row(s) in 0.0370 seconds

Now I had copied the phoenix `4.4.6` jar to the $HBASE_HOME/lib dir, restarted hbase and tried to connect via `sqlline.py`:

```
$sqlline.py mellyrn.local:2181

Setting property: [incremental, false]
Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:mellyrn.local:2181 none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:mellyrn.local:2181
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/shared/phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-bin/phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
16/07/20 22:03:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Class org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl cannot be loaded Set hbase.table.sanity.checks to false at conf or table descriptor if you want to bypass sanity checks
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.warnOrThrowExceptionForFailure(HMaster.java:1603)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.sanityCheckTableDescriptor(HMaster.java:1535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.createTable(MasterRpcServices.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:52195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) (state=08000,code=101)
org.apache.phoenix.except

..

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: Class 
org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl cannot be loaded Set 
hbase.table.sanity.checks to false at conf or table descriptor if you want to 
bypass sanity checks
```

So any hints on what is needed to bring up `phoenix` would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check `$HBASE_HOME/lib` and `$HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-site.xml` on `HMaster`.**

When you start phoenix, it will create 4 system tables:

```
SYSTEM.CATALOG
SYSTEM.FUNCTION
SYSTEM.SEQUENCE
SYSTEM.STATS
```

Table `SYSTEM.CATALOG` and `SYSTEM.FUNCTION` declare to use coprocessor `org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl`, but it seems that your HMaster couldn't load it.

Answer (score 2):

Above exception thrown when HBase master couldn't load the phoenix*server.jar, even though phoenix installation instructions says just restart the region servers, its not enough, copy the phoenix*server.jar to HBase master and backup masters same as region servers and restart all of them.